# Echo Multi Dimensional Array using For Each Loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have created an array mike and john within an array named families. How can I print the values of arrays mike and john using foreach loop

```
   <?php
    $families = array(
        $Mike = array("Mike","abc", "def"),
        $john = array("John","efg", "ghi", "xyz")
    );
   ?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/foreach don't people know what a manual is for anymore?

Comment: Your array syntax is broken too. `$myArr = array( 'myKey' => 'myValue' );`

Answer (score 2):

You should just try, but here is a helper:

```
$families = array(
    'mike' => array(
        'name'=>'Mike', 
        'value1'=>'abc', 
        'value2'=>'def'
        )
);

foreach ($families as $family) {
    echo $family['name'];
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Your solution will iterate over value but if you know the key=value pair already you don't need the additional foreach() statemnet

Comment: @Amal Murali How are you editing my answers? That a feature of you reputation?

Comment: Yes. I had downvoted your question intially but you've corrected it and due to the [time limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes) I was unable to revert the vote. So I just had to edit the question to upvote you. Feel free to change your answer to your liking :)

Answer (score 0):

first, get your array right:

```
<?php
$families = array(
    'Mike' => array("Mike","abc", "def"),
    'john' => array("John","efg", "ghi", "xyz")
);
?>
```

if `$Mike` and `$john` contain the values you want as a key, do this instead:

```
<?php
$families = array();
$families[$Mike] = array("Mike","abc", "def");
$families[$john] = array("John","efg", "ghi", "xyz");
?>
```

now, you can loop over the array:

```
<?php
foreach ($families as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = ";
    print_r($val);
}
?>
```

the $key will be either a numeric index or an explicit key value.

Comment: P.S. `array( $Mike => array("Mike","abc", "def"))` is valid syntax :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat ah :) ok, i've never done that before. apparently still things i can learn about php.

Comment: Learn something new each day :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
<?php
$rockBands = array(
    array('Beatles','Love Me Do', 'Hey Jude','Helter Skelter'),
    array('Rolling Stones','Waiting on a Friend','Angie','Yesterday\'s Papers'),
    array('Eagles','Life in the Fast Lane','Hotel California','Best of My Love')
);
?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>rockBand</th>
    <th>Song 1</th>
    <th>Song 2</th>
    <th>Song 3</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($rockBands as $rockBand)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($rockBand as $item)
    {
        echo "<td>$item</td>";



?>
```

Its working fine at my side... may it help you